# Flask - When a button is pressed how to save the current time

Tags: python, html, flask, button, time

so I have an idea where I have a SWP (Single Web Page) where you click a button and it takes the last time it has been clicked however everyone who visits this page needs to see the time that was set when the button was pressed I will be using Flask in python and html, I just don't know where to start. If anyone could help with the passing the variables on the same web page because other examples I see is loading another page with that variable not on the same page.

So in conclusion I need help on sorting a single page website where anyone can press a button and it displays the time when the button was last clicked. I don't know how to pass Flask variables onto a single webpage that is visible to everyone who visits the page.

Comment: I will link you to a git huub repo

Comment: If you are lost making this, it is probably because you are not familiar enough with Flask, or coding in general. I think you should start from the beginning, follow some tutorials first. Not trying to hate, just being realistic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/cwesterink/last-clicked

Here is code to achieve your goal.
I have implemented comments to help understand.
although if your are new to Flask this may seem confusing.
I suggest looking at "pretty printed" on youtube. He makes great flask tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do a last seen function in flask, visit https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xiii-dates-and-times

Or you can create a model that only has DateTime, then add it to every route, and it will save for every last click, but maybe try to add a relationship between the model and the user model, so it would be easier to view.